# Alcohol to Ketone by CrO3 in cyclohexane

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I have encountered an exercise question on conformation of cyclohexane and there is a statement saying, 'converting alcohol to ketone by CrO3 is much faster when R-OH is in **axial** position'. I would like to know why (but I have not learnt this reaction) and found this on the internet:
[image]

1. in first step, it says the chromate ester has a higher 1,3-diaxial
   interaction, what I interpret is this axial chromate ester
   intermediate is more unstable.

what I can see is the entire chromate ester part is pointing away from the ring, which should  reduce the diaxial interaction eclipsing strain. Can I say this is why the first step (formation of chromate ester) is not the r.d.s. of the entire reaction? Or any other reasons?

2. in the r.d.s (2nd step), it says 'stabilized T.S. as more strain
   released'. What is that 'strain' and how to determine '**more** strain is released'
   than that of equatorial position? my thought: it should not be 1,3-diaxial strain since I can see the entire chromate ester still
   in the same axial position while in T.S.